# Expressjs Post Data

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using body-parser to read the post data but for complex structures the 2nd layer, or object of an object is always passed as a string. For example

i'm passing everything under Customer to `app.post('/newCustomer', function(req, res){` but typeof req.body.Customer is String not Object.

I'm using:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
```

Is there anything that i am not doing correctly or will this always be the case? If it is then i know that i can use JSON.parse() as long as the property names are in speech marks.

```
//update for example code:
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); 
app.post('/newCustomer', function(req, res){
    console.log('typeof', typeof req.body.newcustomer); // this is STRING
});
```

Json Posted:

```
Customer: {
fname: 'jon',     lname: 'smith',     address1: '1 road',     address2: '',     address3: '',     city: 'laguna niguel',     state: 'california',     zipcode: '92677',     mobile: '123-123-1234',     email: 'jon@test.com',     password: 'password'
}
```

Comment: How do you post the data?

Comment: two methods: I'm testing with Advanced Rest Client plugin for Chrome and also an angularjs Iconic app.

Comment: Can you show the real code? Are yo using `application\json` content-type?

Comment: You should show minimal, relevant client code with example data.

Comment: The "Json Posted" you listed isn't valid JSON. Is that the exact text being sent?

Comment: Nice catch. Updated the json and its working correctly - Jonathan if you put this as the answer i'll accept.